# Javascript scrollbar based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a Flash file embedded into HTML - the objects inside are place based on the browser's screen size.

Most of the time I don't want a scroll bar, as things are correctly placed, but once the browser window gets too small it'd be nice to have it.

So, the main question: can I have a Javascript code listening for the browser window, then adding a scroll bar if it's smaller than a certain number?

Many thanks!!

-m

Answer (score 2):

For IE > 6 and all other major browsers, you don't even need JavaScript, a

```
body { min-height: 150px }
```

should do.

[**Compatibility info on min-height on Quirksmode.org**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: @mvita: Be a mensch and mark this question answered, please! :)